# My display name doesn't look how it is supposed to

Tags: software-installation, zsh

I installed "**Oh My Zsh**" in Ubuntu and as I understood my terminal should look like this:

```
➜  ~.
```

I don't understand why instead it looks like this:

```
risy-ZenBook-UX425JA-UX425JA%.
```

Do you know if I maybe did something wrong?

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1375444/edit) the question to add more information about what all commands/steps you had executed. Also, please post a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

From the limited information provided, it looks like `zsh` is installed, but oh-my-zsh isn't being loaded. You should check your `~/.zshrc` to see why `oh-my-zsh` isn't being loaded.

After a successful installation, your `~/.zshrc` should look like [this](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/templates/zshrc.zsh-template).